# starting an intent using spinner and message in edittext

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner, android-button

I want to make a small app that takes value from EDITTEXT, performs an action(defined as spinner item) in SPINNER when a BUTTON is clicked...the onclick action is sendMessage(View view)...could someone tell me how to write this code..I got this much so far

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      addItemsOnSpinner();

}

  public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selection_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.selection_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  }
  public void sendMessage(View view) {
     EditText edittext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message= edittext.getText().toString();

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) {


        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selection_spinner);
        String select=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
       if(select.equals("Call")){
        System.out.println(select);
        // Build the intent(Call)
        Uri number = Uri.parse(message);
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);

        // Verify it resolves
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(callIntent, 0);
        boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

        // Start an activity if it's safe
        if (isIntentSafe) {
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
       }
        if(select.equalsIgnoreCase("E-Mail to")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The value selected is" + select, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The position is" +pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode== 0){
                try{
                        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){    
                            Uri contactData = data.getData();
                            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                            // has result
                            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The name is" +name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The id is" + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                // new query for the mail
                                Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                                 //has result
                                if(emailCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                                    String emailType = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The email is" +email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The emailtype is" +emailType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                                emailCursor.close();
                            }

                            c.close();
                        }

                }
                 catch(Exception e){
                 e.getCause();
                 }        
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place a function inside another function. Your function onItemSelected must be **outside** sendMessage.

Besides, if you only want the selected item at the time when the Button is clicked you don't need OnItemSelectedListener.

This is what I would do (based in your code):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addItemsOnSpinner();

    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selection_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.selection_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        EditText edittext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message= edittext.getText().toString();
            Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selection_spinner);
        String select=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(select.equals("Call")){
            System.out.println(select);
            // Build the intent(Call)
            Uri number = Uri.parse(message);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);

            // Verify it resolves
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(callIntent, 0);
            boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

            // Start an activity if it's safe
            if (isIntentSafe) {
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
        if(select.equalsIgnoreCase("E-Mail to")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode== 0){
            try{
                if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){    
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                    // has result
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The name is" +name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The id is" + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // new query for the mail
                        Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                        //has result
                        if(emailCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                            String emailType = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The email is" +email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The emailtype is" +emailType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        emailCursor.close();
                    }

                    c.close();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.getCause();
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

I just fixed the Spinner and Button part, but I haven't tested it, so the activity change and all that stuff might be wrong.